# Spring MongoDB + QueryDSL query by @DBRef related object

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl, dbref

I am using spring-data-mongodb and querydsl-mongodb to perform more flexible queries.

My application has users and orders.
An user can have multiple orders, so my models looks like this:

```
public class User {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private String username;

 //getters and setters
}

public class Order {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @DBRef
  private User user;

  //getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, there is an has-many relationship between users and orders.
Each order is assigned to an user, and the user is stored in @DBRef public User user attribute.

Now, lets say that an user has 10,000 orders.

How can i make the query to get all orders that belongs to an specific user ?

I have the OrderRepository:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends MongoRepository<Order, String>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Order> {

}
```

I tried this solution but it doesnt return anything:

```
QOrder order = new QOrder("order");
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(0, 100);

return userRepository.findAll(order.user.id.eq(anUserId), pageable);
```

I need to use querydsl because i want to build a service that can query orders by more many prameters than userid. For example i want to get all orders that belongs to user with specific username.

Comment: I just added a related pull request: https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/pull/804

Comment: @TimoWestkämper I'm unable to make the following request work userRepository.findAll(order.user.username.eq(someUsername), pageable);

It works fine with the referenced id userRepository.findAll(order.user.id.eq(anUserId), pageable);

Comment: @Philippe I have the same issue. Did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

No need for `QueryDSL` when searching by ID. In `OrderRepository`, create an interface method:

```
public List<Order> findByUser(String userId);
```

Request example: `curl http://localhost:8080/orders/search/findByUser?userId=5a950ea0a0deb42729b570c0`

* I'm stuck on how to query orders, for example, of all users from certain city (some mongo join with user and address).