# Spring Data query over two documents

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an m:n connection in my MongoDB, **MessageUserConnection** is the class between User and Message.
Now I will get all MessageUserConnections where **MessageUserConnection#confirmationNeeded** is true, read is false and **Message#receiveDate** is not older than the last week. 
Is there any possibility to do this with Spring Data?
Thanks a lot!

```
public class MessageUserConnection {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @DBRef
    private User userCreatedMessage;
    @DBRef
    private Message message;
    private Boolean confirmationNeeded;
    private Boolean read;
}

public class Message {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String message;
    private DateTime receiveDate;
}
```

**[EDIT]**
I have tried it by my own:

```
@Query("FROM MessageUserConnection AS muc WHERE muc.confirmationNeeded = ?0 AND muc.message.receiveDate = ?1")  
List<MessageUserConnection> findMessageUserConnectionByConfirmationNeededAndReceiveDate(final Boolean confirmationNeeded, final DateTime receiveDate);
```

and I get the following exception:

> Caused by: com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
>   FROM MessageUserConnection AS muc WHERE muc.confirmationNeeded = "_param_0" AND muc.message.receiveDate = "_param_1"

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?
Thanks a lot!

**[EDIT]**

I run into another problem. My query currently looks like this.

```
 @Query("{$and : [{'confirmationNeeded' : ?0}, {'message.receiveDate' : ?1}]}")
```

where confirmationNeeded is a boolean and message.receiveDate is Joda#DateTime. With this query I get the following exception:

> org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Invalid path reference message.receiveDate! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!

Does that mean that I only can join to message.id?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually I have tried the whole day yesterday without success. I would be very thankful for any hint in that direction. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you solved it?

Comment: No, its not possible

Comment: Perhaps can be done using QueryDSL?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202259/spring-mongodb-querydsl-query-by-dbref-related-object